# Pasting without auto-indent

Tags: evil, spacemacs

Whenever I paste something in a source code buffer it is automatically re-indented. This is great sometimes, if I'm pasting a complete block of code or a single self contained line for example, but it's awful other times. For example I often assemble fragments together from various places and usually they have at least some existing indentation that I'd prefer to keep.

I've been told I can pass the universal argument to the past command to paste without indentation but "SPC u p" doesn't seem to do anything different.

Is there a way to turn off auto-indent for one paste in Spacemacs or, alternatively, is there a way to disable auto-indent on paste altogether (in that second case it'd be cool to have a command to indent the last pasted block).

Comment: any chance you are running your Emacs under a terminal emulator?

Comment: No, I'm running as a GUI app under OSX (sorry, I should have mentioned that)

Comment: He's speaking about evil's `p` command, not about pasting with the mouse.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable indent on paste altogether with:

```
(setq-default spacemacs-yank-indent-threshold 0)
```

This variable is the size of paste region that is "too large" to auto-indent.  We set it to 0 so that every region is too large.

Comment: Only this work. But when I type C-i, it still indent with wrong tab width.

Emacs indentation makes me crazy.

Answer (score 4):

Go to INSERT mode and then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then paste it with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.