# Why emacs editor changes indent automatically when copy a context into it?

Tags: spacemacs, indentation

I'm using `web-mode` package.

The source(`.tsx file`) in Emacs before:

```
import React from "react";

export default {
  ...
  args: {
    name: "",  // Here
  },
  decorators,
};
```

The source in Emacs after:

```
import React from "react";

export default {
  ...
  args: {
      name: "Awesome",  // Here
  },
  decorators,
};
```

I copied an `Awesome` text from other place and paste it to the editor, the indent changed from 2 to 4 at that line. Why it changed? How to avoid it?

The config in .spacemacs

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (defun tide-setup-hook ()
    (tide-setup)
    (eldoc-mode)
    (tide-hl-identifier-mode +1)
    (setq web-mode-enable-auto-quoting nil)
    (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
    (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
    (setq web-mode-attr-indent-offset 2)
    (setq web-mode-attr-value-indent-offset 2)
    (setq lsp-eslint-server-command '("node" (concat (getenv "HOME") "/var/src/vscode-eslint/server/out/eslintServer.js") "--stdio"))
    (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
    ┆   ┆'((company-tide company-files :with company-yasnippet)
    ┆   ┆  (company-dabbrev-code company-dabbrev))))


dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
┆ (typescript :variables
┆    ┆   ┆   ┆javascript-backend 'tide
┆    ┆   ┆   ┆typescript-fmt-tool 'prettier
┆    ┆   ┆   ┆typescript-linter 'eslint
┆    ┆   ┆   ┆typescript-fmt-on-save t)
```

Comment: Maybe your `indent-level` in this mode is 4 and when you paste the content, it auto indent. You can confirm it with press tab before `name` in your first snippet.

Comment: @TianshuWang Yes, when I type tab it was 4 indent. Then how to change to 2 if use prettier and editorconfig? I already set them to 2. I'm using Spacemacs.

Comment: FWIW pasting text doesn't *normally* trigger any kind of auto-indentation, so that part is something you've configured (I'm going to hazard a guess that you've installed the "aggressive indentation" package, as IIUC it does things like that).

Comment: @phils I checked the `.spacemacs` configuration and didn't find the package `aggressive indentation`. But I find out `highlight-indentation`. I don't know if it did the same thing.

Comment: @phils This only happened for `.tsx` file but `.ts` file works well. I'm using `web-mode`.

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra Spacemacs auto indent when pasting, see [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#auto-indent-pasted-text) and this [issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4219).

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra I suggest you investigate why `editorconfig` doesn't work, i.e., change `default-indent` or maybe `web-mode-markup-indent-offset`.

Comment: @TianshuWang Maybe it's due to the Evil: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/57893/38278

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra You didn't understand what I said, your response and link have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @TianshuWang It resolved the issue in fact.

Comment: @AlpinCleopatra This setup just disable auto indent. If you press `TAB` before `name`, doesn't it still indent at 4 spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have enabled better-defaults layer in spacemacs, if so, then it will automatically indent when you paste (yank).
In order to paste (yank) without indenting, then prefix the command with **C-u**

> C-u C-y

Comment: Yes, I'm using `better-defaults`. But even I disable it still the same as before. I can't understand `C-u C-y` clearly. When I type it there happened nothing.

Comment: C-u C-y means press Ctrl-u, then Ctrl-y

Comment: Another solution, this way works: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/57893/38278